# SQL Query union two tables, search multiple columns by multiple keywords

Tags: sql, linq, dapper

I am having difficulty in creating a query or stored procedure which can search my results by keyword.

My SQL Fiddle is here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/48eaa8/1/0

I need to be able to allow my users to search by keywords.

For example, in the above fiddle, the user should be able to enter 'sony colour' or 'sony 87154316459' to find results across multiple columns.

How would I go about doing this in a stored procedure? I have edited my code for brevity so it is a lot more complex than this. Unfortunately it cannot be translated to SQL from Linq.

Comment: Maybe we can start from question, why not LINQ? What is the complexity?

Comment: If you joined the two fields as you suggest, you wouldn't be able to do "Monitor Sony".

Comment: I have simplified the matter substantially. I did post a question prior where the LINQ was unable to be translated into SQL successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered making your query into a list so that instead of using "like" you are doing something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ManufacturerName In ('Sony','Monitor') OR ProductName in ('Sony','Monitor')
```

Based on your question update, the original concept holds and the stored proc would look like:

```
Create Table Product (
  ProductId int,
  ManufacturerId varchar(50),
  ProductName varchar(50),
  Upc varchar(50)
);
Create Table ProductVariation (
  ProductVariationId int,
  ProductId int,
  VariationName varchar(50),
  Upc varchar(50)
);
Create Table Manufacturer (
  ManufacturerId int,
  ManufacturerName varchar(50)
);
GO
Create OR ALTER Procedure p_SearchProduct(@searchList varchar(max))
AS
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @searchValue varchar(max);
      set @searchValue = '%' + Replace(@searchList,' ','%') + '%';
      BEGIN
      with SearchList
      as
      (
      SELECT value as SearchItem
      FROM STRING_SPLIT(@searchList, ' ')  
      WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(value)) <> ''  
      ), SearchData as
      (
        SELECT
        p.ProductId,
        NULL AS 'ProductVariationid',
        m.ManufacturerName,
        ProductName,
        UPC
        FROM Product p
        INNER JOIN Manufacturer m ON m.ManufacturerId = p.ManufacturerId
        UNION
        SELECT 
        v.ProductId,
        v.ProductVariationId,
        m.ManufacturerName,
        p.ProductName + ' (' + v.VariationName + ')' AS 'ProductName',
        v.UPC
        FROM ProductVariation v
        INNER JOIN Product p ON p.ProductId = v.ProductId
        INNER JOIN Manufacturer m ON m.ManufacturerId = p.ManufacturerId
      )
      SELECT * FROM SearchData p
      where p.ProductName like @searchValue
      OR exists ( select 'x' from SearchList where p.UPC like '%' + SearchItem + '%')
      END
    END
GO
insert into Manufacturer Values(1,'Sony');
insert into Product Values(1,1,'Sony Monitor (Variable)','');
insert into Product Values(2,1,'Sony Walkman','32164578121');
insert into ProductVariation Values(1,1,'32" Colour','87154316458');
insert into ProductVariation Values(1,1,'48" Colour','87154316459');

exec p_SearchProduct 'Sony 87154316458';
```

You would call it with

```
exec p_SearchProduct 'sony colour';
OR
exec p_SearchProduct 'sony 87154316458';
```

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion, Chuma. My SQL fiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/48eaa8/1/0 this will show you how I union my two tables. Are you able to see how I would apply your solution to my schema? I have updated my original question for clarity. Thank you

Comment: The concept I think remains the same - split the search words into a delimited array and search but this time using a like. Decided to change the delimiter to a space to match what you have

Comment: Many thanks for the updated Fiddle. Nearly there but if you exec your new proc, the Sony Walkman appears. I would expect this not to appear as it does not have the word "colour" anywhere. I assume I need to use some sort of AND operation somewhere but I am drawing a bit of a blank...

Comment: That's because it's in the manufacturer's name. So you need to decide what fields to go against. So you need to remove the manufacturer's name if you don't want that to be part of the fields search. The other thing you could do is change the OR conditions to an AND condition in the stored proc and that would solve the problem. I'm using the original OR conditions you had when you first asked the question. At this point, you should be able to adapt it for your use.

Comment: Would it be better if I combined all of the fields I need into one computed column which would read 'sony Monitor (Variable) (48" Colour) 87154316459". I could then change the proc so that ALL words "sony" "colour" need to be in the computed field? Thank  you

Comment: Could work but not as clean and you create overhead. If you could preload a table with the combined fields and add an index, perhaps that would be ok.

Comment: No unfortunately none of these suggestions work. I remember coming up against the same problem years ago and getting nowhere. If you check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e7f92/2/0, I created a calculated field and searched for "sony,walkman". The Sony Monitors are appearing which is incorrect.

Comment: This may show the issue in a better way: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6a2848/1/0 You will note that I have created a computed column. The only results that should be appearing when I search for "sony,walkman" should be the walkman.

Comment: SQL Fiddle appears to be down but I caught a glimpse of what you had. From all indications, from your examples and mine, the issue is the manufacturer. As long as it remains as part of the search condition, it will not meet the expectations you expect because what it really appears you are looking for is a search on product name or UPC. I made a change to the answer. You could go ahead and concatenate too without the manufacturer name and it should resolve your issue. Couldn't add the fiddle but will once it comes up. Next time, in your question show expected results to get here faster.

Comment: Hi Chuma SQL fiddle is back up. Are you up to show me? Thank you

Comment: So I took the exact code I have in my answer, ran it in SSMS for SS 2016 and 2017 and it ran ok and produced the correct result. In SQL Fiddle, there's some known issue with a lack of tolerance for declare statements and so keeps erroring out and when entered directly in the where clause, for some reason it doesn't work. So if you have a local DB, run it as I have it there. I added these lines in mine but you probably don't need to: drop procedure p_SearchProduct;
drop table Product;
drop table ProductVariation;
drop table Manufacturer;

Comment: Thank you, Chuma. I did try locally and it works for 'sony monitor' but not for 'monitor sony'. I am going to give up on this for the time being and stick to standard search. I don't think keyword searches like this are possible without full text indexing etc.

Comment: Or elastic search. I think only the person having the full picture of requirements like you will know what's best. The concept is sound and how much one can stretch it depends on detailed proper requirements. Right now as is, it would be just be a curious game of whack-a-mole.